# Show the sequence number of an article in Drupal

Tags: drupal, module, view

i have used views created an article's title page list of the content type story. now,i want to add the sequence number of the article before the article's title .eg: if i have 200 articles. it maybe 1 the first article title ,2 the second  article title  ...198 the 198th  article title,199 the 199th  article title ,200 the 200th  article title. how to  get this. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

in views, you can add a field: Global -> view result counter
This field gives you a numeric value which indicates the position of the view result row.

so after adding a title field and the counter field,you get for example

-Title: blablabla

View result counter: 1

-Title: blablabla

View result counter: 2

-Title: blablabla

View result counter: 3

...

you can ofcourse change the label or dismiss it completely

Answer (score 1):

You can format your view as a numbered list. Under "Basic settings" set "Style" to "HTML List". In the style options, choose "Ordered list".

Comment: but when at the next page,the number begins at number one again.